# Azure pipeline vcpkg install outputs "Error getting canonicalization"

Tags: azure, vcpkg

I'm trying to make the vcpkg to install a package using azure pipeline(azure-pipelines.yml)

```
- script: git submodule update --init vcpkg
  displayName: Checkout vcpkg submodule
- script: .\vcpkg\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
  displayName: Bootstrap vcpkg
- script: .\vcpkg\vcpkg.exe install grpc
  displayName: vcpkg install grpc
```

I get the following error on the last script(`.\vcpkg\vcpkg.exe install grpc`):

```
Starting: vcpkg install grpc
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.164.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents:
.\vcpkg\vcpkg.exe install grpc
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\558be028-1311-4d58-bec5-de4d14ebe1bb.cmd""
Error getting canonicalization of D:\a\1\s\ports: The system cannot find the file specified.
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
Finishing: vcpkg install grpc
```

What could be the problem? How can I debug this?

Comment: have you given a look at this example - https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/examples/installing-and-using-packages.md . is it possible the name of the package you are installing is incorrect?